# Fetching uploaded images using Link URL

Tags: images, media-library

I am trying to fetch the uploaded images using the link URL (The Link URL option is available in the **Add Media** when we upload/insert media) and display it on web.
I have gone through the methods `has_post_thumbnail` and `the_post_thumbnail` which are working perfect for me. Now, i am trying to display images (other than featured image) with certain sizing options (as available in `the_post_thumbnail`).

I am using the Link URL associated with the uploaded image with the help of the function   `$im =imagecreatefromjpeg($url[image]);` and `imagejpeg($im);` to display it on web but all it displays it is special characters !

Is there a way to do it ?

**Update code for fetching a single image from media library:**

```
$media_query = new WP_Query
(
          array(
          'post_parent' => get_the_ID(), 
          'post_type' => 'attachment', 
          'post_status' => 'inherit',
          'post_title' => $url[image]
          )
);

foreach ($media_query->posts as $post) 
{
  print_r(wp_get_attachment_image($post->ID));
  $imageFound = true;
  break;
}
```

`$url[image]` contains the `post_title`. The problem is this query is fetching all the images from the media library ! Am i missing something ?

Comment: I'm not clear on exactly what you're trying to do, or why you're creating a new image with GD (which seems extremely inefficient). Maybe you want [`wp_get_attachment_image_src`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src)?

Comment: Well,i have uploaded an image in the media library from my hard drive. I want to fetch that uploaded image re-size it into a thumbnail and display it on the browser when i publish it..all of this programmatically.. is there a way to do it ?

Comment: attachments are children of the post they are attached to. see [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Show_attachments_for_the_current_post) function to fetch attachment IDs for use with `wp_get_attachment_image_src`.

Comment: i just want one image (based on the `post_title` say). So i am using 'WP_Query' to fetch the image from DB. The result though is fetching all images from the media !! Can you suggest something ?

Comment: I have got the solution. I went through the documentation and it said that `post_title` is actually recognized in DB by `name` attribute.I changed my query accordingly and it fetches only one image as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> I want to fetch that uploaded image re-size it into a thumbnail and
>   display it on the browser when i publish it..all of this
>   programmatically.. is there a way to do it?

You don't need to do this manually. The [add_image_size()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size) function and the [wp_get_attachment_image_src()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src) function allow you to create and display alternate sizes for uploaded images.

Rather than running imagecreatefromjpeg() on every page load (which I assume is what you're doing based on your question), you can just create the images on upload (i.e., once).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is  either wp_get_attachment_image : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image or perhaps one of the related functions.

Comment: wp_get_attachment_image_src or wp_get_attachment_image takes an attachment_id as a parameter. What do i supply over here ? can i supply the link URL to it ? or the file name of the attached image ?